# Can code be run automatically in the Firebase backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code that runs on a particular page on my Angular JS website:

```
    databaseService.users.child(user.uid).on('value', function(usersSnapshot){
    var users = usersSnapshot.val();
    var total = users.total;

     var week1 = users.week1;
    var week2 = users.week2;
    var week3 = users.week3;
    var week4 = users.week4;
    var week5 = users.week5;
    var week6 = users.week6;
    var week7 = users.week7;
    var week8 = users.week8;
    var week9 = users.week9;
    var week10 = users.week10;
    var week11 = users.week11;
    var week12 = users.week12;

    var addition = week1 + week2 + week3 + week4 + week5 + week6 + week7 + week8 + week9 + week10 + week11 + week12;

    var seasonTotal = firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("total");

  seasonTotal.set(addition);
```

My problem is that the code only runs if the user logs on and goes to the view in which the code is run. But I want that addition to run for every user, both signed in and not. Is this possible with firebase? Maybe a cloud function?

Comment: Yup. That sounds like a great use-case for [Cloud Functions with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You'll likely want to [trigger when a user updates the weeks in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). Feel free to post back if you have trouble implementing it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I am having an issue implementing it: can i call firebase database refs within the cloud functions? I keep getting the rror message : "firebase is not defined at exports."

Comment: You'll typically import the Firebase Admin SDK and use that. If you follow the docs I linked before, it'll show how to do this and more. If you're having problems making it work, update your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).